# Sublime Text cannot recognize NumberFormat

Tags: java, sublimetext3, number-formatting

I have the following simple code in a (Windows 10) sublime text 3 file `NumberFormat.java`, to format a double to US currency:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

public class NumberFormat {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double num = 1000.322;
        NumberFormat defaultFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        System.out.println("US: " + defaultFormat.format(num));
        return;
    }
}
```

When I build, however, the follow errors show up exclusively for NumberFormat.

```
NumberFormat.java:2: error: NumberFormat is already defined in this compilation unit
import java.text.NumberFormat;
^
NumberFormat.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
        NumberFormat defaultFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
                                                 ^
  symbol:   method getCurrencyInstance()
  location: class NumberFormat
NumberFormat.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println("US: " + defaultFormat.format(num));
                                                 ^
  symbol:   method format(double)
  location: variable defaultFormat of type NumberFormat
3 errors
```

As far as I can see, there are no errors with the code. In addition, this code snippet outputs `US: $1000.32` as it should on all other IDEs and text editors. Can someone explain what these errors mean? And why they exclusively occur with sublime text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should modify your class name to a class that is different from the imported class name,or you can change you source to

`java.text.NumberFormat defaultFormat = java.text.NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();`

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you have imported a class called `NumberFormat` into a class with the same name.  This is resulting in confusion over which class `NumberFormat` actually refers to.

(The confusion is in your mind actually.  The Java language spec is clear about it.  It says that `NumberFormat` will refer exclusively to your class.  The import has not effect.  Any compliant Java compiler will make the same interpretation.)

There are two solutions:

1. Don't import the class.  Instead refer to it using its fully qualified name.
2. Change the name of your class so that it doesn't collide with the class you are importing.

To my mind, the second solution is better.  Especially since `NumberFormat` is not a good name for your class anyway.

---

> And why they exclusively occur with sublime text?

They don't.  The code you have written won't compile with any conformant Java compiler.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an issue of Sublime. Sublime simply invokes the javac command from your path. You get the same result if you compile using javac outside the sublime

changing class name or be part of an explicit package name solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

The

> import java.text.NumberFormat

conflicts with a type defined in the same file. Changing your class name would resolve the problem.